# "grub-mkconfig" doesn't execute os-prober

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I'm trying to install Arch alongside Windows on my new laptop. (Forced to use Windows for school)

When I run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` it says

```
...
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
...
```

Comment: I tried adding `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to /etc/default/grub, but now it just gives me "/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1" infinitely